# Как сделать замену отдельных элементов?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Как сделать так, чтобы по клику на конкретный `div`, он менялся на `textarea` и по клику на кнопку (в моем случае "Сохранить"), конкретная `textarea` менялась обратно на `div`?

Функция, которая привязана к `ng-click`:

```
$scope.mode = 'division';
$scope.EditTask = function (task) {
    if ($scope.mode == 'division') {
        $scope.mode = 'area';
    } else if ($scope.mode == 'area') {
        $scope.mode = 'division'
    }
};
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="task in tasks">
<div ng-switch on="mode">
    <div ng-switch-when="area">
        <textarea ng-model="task">{[ task.text_task ]}</textarea>
        <button ng-click="EditTask($event)">Сохранить</button>
        <button ng-click="DeleteTask(task)">Удалить</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="division">
        <div ng-model="data" ng-click="EditTask($event)">{[ task.text_task ]}</div>
        <button ng-click="DeleteTask(task)">Удалить</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Сейчас, когда я кликаю на `div`, все дивы меняются на `textarea` (что, в общем-то, логично, смотря на мой код), но мне нужно сделать как я описал в начале вопроса, но я не могу догадаться как это сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем виде это надо делать так.

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/9payd0j3/)

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.tasks = [{
      text_task: "text_task",
      mode: 'area'
    }, {
      text_task: "text_task 1",
      mode: 'area'
    }, {
      text_task: "text_task 2",
      mode: 'area'
    }, {
      text_task: "text_task 3",
      mode: 'area'
    }];
    vm.EditTask = function(task) {
      if (task.mode == 'division') {
        task.mode = 'area';
      } else if (task.mode == 'area') {
        task.mode = 'division'
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
    <div ng-repeat="task in vm.tasks">
      <div ng-switch on="task.mode">
        <div ng-switch-when="area">
          <textarea ng-model="task.text_task"></textarea>
          <button ng-click="vm.EditTask(task)">Сохранить</button>
          <button ng-click="DeleteTask(task)">Удалить</button>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="division">
          <div ng-click="vm.EditTask(task)">{{task.text_task }}</div>
          <button ng-click="DeleteTask(task)">Удалить</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```